# Form submit from autocomplete search box

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I am building a website using CodeIgniter with Bootstrap and I have a form with two search fields in the header of each page.

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/search/searchData" method="post" name="searchf" class="form Searchf" id="searchForm">
<input name="A1"  class="menu-link Searchbox S1" id="S1"/>
<input name="A2" class="menu-link Searchbox S2" id="S2"/>
<input type="submit" id="submitSearchA"/>
</form>
```

For each of the two search fields(S1 and S2) I have an Auto-Complete list where a specific item can be selected.

```
$('#S1').typeahead({
 source: function (query, process) {
  return $.post(base_url + 'index.php/search/autocomplete/', { query: query, database : "airlines" }, function (data) {
  return process(data);
       });
    }
});


$('#S2').typeahead({
source: function (query, process) {
return $.post(base_url + 'index.php/search/autocomplete/', { query: query, database : "airports" }, function (data) {
return process(data);
     });
  }
});
```

The autocomplete is a Bootstrap class with the following code:

```
<ul class="typeahead dropdown-menu" role="listbox" style="top: 50px; left: 287px; display: none;">
 <li class=""><a href="#" role="option">...</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" role="option">...</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" role="option">...</a></li>
 .....
 <li class="active"><a href="#" role="option"></a></li>
 ....
 <li><a href="#" role="option">....</a></li>
</ul>
```

What I want is a code in jquery so that once an item ('a') is clicked from the dropdown list, the form submission should be triggered. In Bootstrap the clicked item is below a li class="active" as you can see in the above code.

Please find below my attempt.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('ul.typeahead').each(function(){
    var $itemclicked = $('li.active').find('a');
    $itemclicked.on('click',function(){   
      $('#searchForm').submit();
    });
 });
</script>
```

But nothing is happening.....

For reference, I have found a function that works perfectly but only if the user presses enter:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Using jQuery.

$(function() {
    $('form').each(function() {
        $(this).find('input').keypress(function(e) {
            // Enter pressed?
            if(e.which == 10 || e.which == 13) {
                this.form.submit();
            }
        });

        $(this).find('input[type=submit]').hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

I have tried to customize this to work for mouseout but no had luck.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

A JSFiddle would help, but try this anyway:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var item = $("ul.typeahead").find("li.active");
      item.on("click", "a", function(){
        $("#searchForm").submit();
      });
    });
</script>
```

**What am I doing:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){    .....    });
```

This ensures all your code get executed when the DOM is ready, in other words when all the page has been loaded by the browser.
Usually you want to put all your code inside the 'document ready'

**traversing**

```
var item = $("first-elem").find("second-elem");

item.on("click", "third-elem", function(){   .....   })
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap would change the selected item to 'active' on click. So you should try to bind the click event to just the li tag. Can you try the following snippet?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('ul.typeahead li').on('click',function(){   
        $('#searchForm').submit();
     });
  });      
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, Deva but it doesn't trigger the form submit.

Comment: @RoxanaRaicu What does the console say?

Comment: It doesn't display any error...or please tell me what else should I look for?

Comment: Do a console.log in click callback and check if the function is being called first?

Comment: What about binding the click event on the <a> tag inside the <li> tag without the .active class?

Comment: Ok, Deva - I have inserted a console.log text immediately before  $('#searchForm').submit(); and nothing was displayed in the console after i clicked an item.

Comment: thank you, Deva - it does work in jfiddle and it is a very logical sequence ...maybe the issue has to do with the fact that the list is not displayed upfront but only when an item is searched...

Comment: Instead of "display: none", can you try "display: hidden" for the ul tag? The element will not be in DOM during the click event binding.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution - I have done a little more research and it seems that it is not easy to attach a click or another event to Bootstrap dropdown menu - but after many attempts here is what it worked in my case.

```
$(window).load(function(){
 $('body').on('mousedown','a',{role:'option'},function(e){
  $('#submitSearchA').trigger('click');  
  });
});
```

Comment: I suspect the problem to be in the form being submitted before the typeahead function could place the correct query inside the input tag.
Anyway, glad you found your solution.
If you can, post your source/explanation and mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) function.

```
$(this).closest("form").submit();
```

So your code becomes ...

```
var $itemclicked = $('li.active').find('a');
$itemclicked.on('click',function(){   
  $(this).closest("form").submit(); // <= Here we are making the nearest form to submit.
});
```